# ruby plugin/gem to convert cron into a human readable format

Tags: ruby, cron, rubygems

Is there a ruby gem/plugin which will convert something like */10 * * * 1,3 to "Triggers every 10 minutes on Monday, Wednesday" ?

Comment: it's not exactly what you want, but maybe it'll help: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing I know of and I also didn't find anything with Google. You may be able to hack something together on your own though:

```
>> cron = "*/10 * * * 1,3 foo" 
#=> "*/10 * * * 1,3 foo"
>> min, hour, dom, month, dow, command = cron.split 
#=> ["*/10", "*", "*", "*", "1,3", "foo"]
```

Once you have the vars, you can start assembling the parts for your output:

```
>> require 'date' 
#=> true
>> dow.split(/,/).map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES[day.to_i] } 
#=> ["Monday", "Wednesday"]
>> min.start_with?('*') ? "every #{min.split('/')[1]} minutes" : "#{min} past" 
#=> "every 10 minutes"
>> min = '5' 
#=> "5"
>> min.start_with?('*') ? "every #{min.split('/')[1]} minutes" : "#{min} past" 
#=> "5 past"
```

Obviously that's just some rough ideas (for example you may want a regex with capture groups for parsing the entry), but since the crontab entries are well specified, it shouldn't be too hard to come up with something that works for most of the entries you are likely to encounter.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Ruby gem to do this, based on Sean Burke's Perl script:

https://github.com/pjungwir/cron2english

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for :)

http://www.joostbrugman.com/bitsofthought/page/4/Converting_Crontab_Entries_To_Plain_English_%28Or_Any_Other_Language%29

http://crontranslator.appspot.com/

Comment: Those two examples are nice, but are in PHP and Javascript (respectively) so would have to be converted to Ruby to meet the questioners needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Ruby gem cronex
https://github.com/alpinweis/cronex